# Pybind11: external type as return value

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

With pybind11 I need to bind a function that returns an object type whose binding is already available from another extension module (also created with pybind11). I know this is generally possible since [the docs say so](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#partitioning-code-over-multiple-extension-modules) and I've also managed to build a [complete toy example where things work fine](https://github.com/simleo/pybind11_examples/tree/master/multi_ext). However, for some reason I don't understand, I cannot make it work If the external type is the `Tensor` type from https://github.com/deephealthproject/pyeddl. I know that `-fvisibility=hidden` is not an issue because:

- it's also present in the toy example;
- I've also tried rebuilding pyeddl without it.

`src/dummy_bindings.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <eddl/tensor/tensor.h>

Tensor* mkTensor() {
    return new Tensor();
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(_foo, m) {
    m.def("mkTensor", &mkTensor);
}
```

`setup.py`:

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import pybind11

ext = Extension(
    "_foo",
    sources=["src/dummy_bindings.cpp"],
    include_dirs=[
        "src",
        pybind11.get_include(),
        pybind11.get_include(user=True)
    ],
    libraries=["eddl"],
)

setup(
    name="foo",
    ext_modules=[ext]
)
```

Test python code:

```py
import pyeddl._core
import _foo

print(pyeddl._core.Tensor)
t = _foo.mkTensor()
```

This leads to:

```
<class 'pyeddl._core.Tensor'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 5, in <module>
    t = _foo.mkTensor()
TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was
    () -> Tensor
```

My understanding is that the `import pyeddl._core` should make the `Tensor` type visible at runtime and make the call to `mkTensor` work. At least, it does work in the toy example. However, I get the above error. I'm also the author of the pyeddl bindings, so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong there that prevents the type from being findable by other extensions. Or perhaps there is something more about the way pybind11 decides if a value can be converted to a Python type that I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it didn't work is that the two extensions were compiled with **different versions of gcc**.